# AngularJS pass model to controller in live update

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

The two way binding in AngularJs is great in updating the view anytime the model changes. I was wondering if there was some way to pass the model to a function defined in the controller before being displayed. And not with a button click but live.

So for example, the `p` element would be updated automatically

```
<input data-ng-model='myModel'>
<p>{{myModel}}</p>
```

Is there any way to do the following?

```
<div data-ng-controller='myController'>
    <input data-ng-model='myModel'>
    <p>{{increment(myModel)}}</p>
</div>
```

where increment is a function defined in `myController`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most definitely you can. Just define the function in the same controller. For instance

Controller:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.increment = function() {
        return $scope.myModel;
    }

});
```

HTML

```
<div data-ng-controller='myController'>
    <input data-ng-model='myModel'>
    <p>{{increment()}}</p>
</div>
```

That returns the exact same thing as {{myModel}}